# Spectral Reconstruction

Tags: image-processing

I have a small system which consist of: Led Clusters, camera(RGB or grayscale) and an object to be detected. I am emitting a light from the LED clusters (ex: yellow). After emitting light on the object, I am capturing an image for the object from the camera.
I want to get the spectral image of the object from the captured image. Please if any one knows the algorithm or a code for this purpose(grayscale or RGB camera), tell me.
Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compute the Fourier transform of the captured image, is that correct? If that's the case I think [this](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/dft/) could be a good start point

Answer (score 0):

You want the color spectrum of an image but you only have an R,G,B value?

Good luck with that

Comment: of course you can if you use the environment i talked about. please see the paper in http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/projects/multispectral_imaging/
It describes that thoroughly.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a spectrum - at best it's color balanced.